# PayPal SDK in android

Tags: android, paypal

I have imported the PayPalSDKExample and I've set to Sandbox environment, I was trying to execute in Emulator, its saying, "Payment from this device are not allowed"

How to resolve this, for Networkless environment, It was working well.

Comment: i have configured paypal long back but remember that there are permission of paypal have u added that?

Comment: No I havent added such. What's that? How can I add that one?

Comment: hey ur question says "How to resolve this, for Networkless environment, It was working well." do u mean it run on other device?? is ur application runnning first of all???

Comment: No, we have 3 PaymentActivity Environment
PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK
In this environment, its working. Just a Demo Envirnoment, but in 
PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX
In this not working.

Comment: ok can u post ur manifest xml here may be i can help you

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

From this I downloaded the project, I have imported the Sample App.

Pls go through that, and help me to integratr with Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you've set the `client_id` to the value given to you by https://developer.paypal.com. Note also that there are separate `client_id` values for production and sandbox.

Comment: I know this. Same line gave in that instruction. In developer.paypal.com I couldn't find anything named as client_id

Comment: You'll need to go to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps, log in, and create an application.

Answer (score 1):

(Log In - With PayPal account) First enter here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

Then: Choose "Create Application" In this step, you need to choose Mobile SDK insted of Web. Write a name of your app and the press the button 'create'.

Finish this, press in the name of your app and choose REST API CREDENTIALS

inside ther you will see something like: "Test Credentials" and "Live Credentials" in test credentials are client_id tag, well copy that tag, something like:

aafsdsdssdsf3434famAp_o0Rdafadsafa334__O

then in your app have something like and paste the cliend_id here:

```
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE to move real money.
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials from https://developer.paypal.com
// set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires without communicating to PayPal's servers.
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
***private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "PASTE HERE";***
// when testing in sandbox, this is likely the -facilitator email address. 
private static final String CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "matching paypal email address";
```

finish run your app again.

Remember this code are inside "MainActivity.java" inside PayPalSDK